# Python error : TypeError at / unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool'

Tags: python, html, css, pandas

Good morning all !
I come to ask for your support. I'm trying to make a selection on the data in my dataframe and since then I'm getting an error. I'm new to Python and I'm stuck on an error that's taking me a long time.
Below is my code:

```
if requete.method == 'POST':
    myfile = requete.FILES['file']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
    uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, filename), sep=";", encoding='unicode_escape')
    array = [
        'Bundle_Weekly_400MB', 'Bundle_Daily_40MB', 
        'Bundle_Daily_150MB', 'Bundle_Daily_10MB', 'Bundle_Weekly_100MB',
    ]
    df = df.loc[df['EXTERNAL_DATA1'] == 'dataBundle'] & df.loc[df['EXTERNAL_DATA2'].isin(array)]
```

Below is the error I got:

[image]

Comment: I've edited your code to be formatted better. Please help us help you solve your problems :) can you share what the first few rows of `df` look like? Also what is your expected output? Which line is your error happening at?

Comment: Hi! My problem is solved. the following line was incorrectly written: df = df.loc[(df['EXTERNAL_DATA1'] == 'dataBundle') & (df['EXTERNAL_DATA2'].isin(array))]. Thank you for the support